# Java Subtract lines

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, graphics, java-2d

So I have a simple rectangle drawn on the screen with vertical lines that run down it's sides. So it looks something like this:
[image]

That line is actually 1 full line running from the top of the screen all the way to the bottom, it just looks kinda cut off. But what I want to do is split that 1 line up into 2 lines where ever it intersects the rectangle. So it would look like this:
[image]

What I was thinking was have a line running down the left side of the rectangle (from the top-left vertex to the bottom-left vertex) and then subtract that line from the full line to get the 2 resultant lines.

But Java doesn't have a line subtract function so I'm kinda lost...plus I think there is some better way. Any ideas?

Comment: A little more complicated, but have a look at [`Area`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Area.html) it has add and subtrct and other funationality...

Comment: @MadProgrammer  The trick here is to use a very thin `Rectangle2D` instead of a `Line2D`.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I think I would still just calculate two separate lines to start with...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use Java-2D for this.

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.*;

class RectangleSubtractedFromLines {

    public static BufferedImage getImage() {
        BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(600,200,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

        Graphics2D g = bi.createGraphics();

        Rectangle2D rect = new Rectangle2D.Double(50,50,100,100);
        // we never draw this, it is used as an area slightly bigger than 
        // the actual rectangle, to subract from the lines to give them space.
        int pad = 8;
        Rectangle2D rectBuffer = new Rectangle2D.Double(
                50-pad,50-pad,100+(2*pad),100+(2*pad));

        // we cannot form an Area from a Line2D, however 
        // we CAN form an Area from a (very thin) Rectangle2D
        Rectangle2D line1 = new Rectangle2D.Double(0,50,600,.02d);
        Rectangle2D line2 = new Rectangle2D.Double(0,149.98,600,.02d);

        Area lines = new Area(line1);
        lines.add(new Area(line2));
        lines.subtract(new Area(rectBuffer));

        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.setStroke(new BasicStroke(
                3, BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND, BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND));
        g.draw(rect);

        g.setColor(Color.MAGENTA.darker().darker());
        g.setStroke(new BasicStroke(
                6, BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND, BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND));
        g.draw(lines);

        g.dispose();

        return bi;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JLabel gui = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(
                        RectangleSubtractedFromLines.getImage()));

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, gui);
            }
        };
        // Swing GUIs should be created and updated on the EDT
        // http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If this is only a rectangle you can use the `minY` and `maxY` methods of the rectangle class (actually inherited from the `RectangularShape` class)

```
 // line 1 (your orange one)
 double x1 = rectangle.getMinX();
 double y1 = 0;
 double x2 = rectangle.getMinX();
 double y2 = rectangle.getMinY();

 // line 2 (your blue one)
 double x1 = rectangle.getMinX();
 double y1 = rectangle.getMaxY();
 double x2 = rectangle.getMinX();
 double y2 = conainer.getHeight(); // height of the container your painting your rectangle in I assume?
```

If you are working with more advanced shapes then you should look into the `Area` class mentioned by @MadProgrammer